# Using default AWS settings to compute in the cloud is very slow for me

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been playing around with the exciting new Amazon Web Services (AWS) batch cloud computation facility in Mathematica 12.2. I'm wondering what has been the experience of others on this forum? My personal experience so far is that if I use the default settings as explained in the [example AWS workflow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SetUpTheAWSBatchComputationProvider.html), then my jobs are running about 100 times slower on the AWS EC2 cloud than they run on my local PC. I'm using a free AWS account on AWS. I haven't yet played around with the default settings.

Comment: can you provide more details about the jobs you are running?  (example would help).  Is it compute intensive, data intensive, using a lot of parallelism, etc.?

Comment: Ditto @JoshuaSchrier - it would be helpful if you could provide a working example.
Someone else [posted](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2169240) on Wolfram Community about similar problems, although not as severe. I gave some general pointers there, but it's hard to diagnose performance problems without knowing exactly what the code is doing.